# Multi condition JOIN ON column?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to make a join that joins a column from *table a* with 2 columns from *table b*?

Here's a quick example of my situation:

```
**Flight**
  idFlight     Flightnumber     Date          idDepart    idArrival
  1            5871             2018-02-03    1           2
  2            5872             2018-03-08    1           3
  3            5873             2018-03-19    3           2
  4            5874             2018-04-11    2           1
  5            5875             2018-04-21    3           2

**Airport**
  idAirport     Code     Name
  1             AMS      Amsterdam Airport Schiphol
  2             JFK      John F Kennedy International Airport
  3             TXL      Berlijn Tegel Airport
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have an overview of where flights depart and arrive in one query. Here's what I have got so far:

```
SELECT Flight.Flightnumber, Flight.Date, Airport.Name AS 'Arriving at' FROM Flight
LEFT JOIN Airport ON Flight.idArrival = Airport.idAirport
```

But can't seem to figure out how I can have `Flight.idDepart` on `Airport.idAirport` as well to create another alias "Departing from". Joining Airport twice doesn't work so I tried using a subquery like this:

```
SELECT Flight.Flightnumber, Flight.Date, Airport.Name AS 'Arriving at',
    ( SELECT Airport.Name AS 'Departing from' FROM Flight
        LEFT JOIN Airport ON Flight.idDepart = Airport.idAirport ) 
    FROM Flight
LEFT JOIN Airport ON Flight.idArrival = Airport.idAirport
```

What would be the right or best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you the result set you are looking for:

```
SELECT f.FlightNumber, f.FlightDate, d.Name AS departAirport, a.Name AS arrivalAirport
FROM Flight AS f
LEFT JOIN Airport AS d ON f.idDepart = d.idAirport
LEFT JOIN Airport AS a ON f.idArrival = a.idAirport
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try two left join with airport 1 for departure and 1 for arrival,

Try following query.

```
SELECT 
f.Flightnumber, 
f.date, 
a.name AS dept, 
a1.name AS arrvl 
FROM 
flight f LEFT JOIN airport a ON a.idAirport = f.idDepart 
LEFT JOIN airport a1  ON a1.idAirport = f.idArrival
```

Try demo [Here](http://rextester.com/POPA16730)

Answer (score 0):

You can alias each query, something like this (***untested***) :

```
SELECT flights.FlightNumber, flights.FlightDate, departures.Name, arrivals.Name 
FROM (SELECT * FROM Flight) AS flights 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Airport) AS departures ON flights.idDepart = departures.idAirport
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Airport) AS arrivals ON flights.idArrival = arrivals .idAIrport
```

Comment: (SELECT * FROM Flight)  - from flight as flights would do.

Comment: The additional `SELECT * FROM` is not required and will cause full table scans.

Answer (score 0):

Try a correlated sub query

```
   SELECT Flight.Flightnumber, Flight.Date, Airport.Name AS 'Arriving at',
        ( SELECT Airport.Name from Airport ON Flight.idDepart = Airport.idAirport) as 'Departing From'
    FROM Flight
    JOIN Airport ON Flight.idArrival = Airport.idAirport
```